# How to deploy and debug wdk 8 kernel mode driver

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, device-driver, wdk

I’m trying to set up automatic driver deployment and debugging to  test a win 8.1 driver from Visual Studio 2013.

Host machine:
Win 7
VS2013

Target Machine:
Win 8.1

My host machine is set up with 2 network cards, 1 which connects to the corporate network and one spare. The target machine also has a network adapter.

My question is: is it possible to set up automatic deployment and debugging of drivers in Visual studio 2013 by connecting the host and target via a LAN whilst still being connected to the corporate domain and if not, is there a way of debugging wdk drivers on a target pc outside of visual studio, maybe via another application?

The documentation I found here only makes it seem possible by connecting to the same domain name or workgroup.

[link to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can set up automatic deployment of the driver as well as getting visual studio to do the provisioning of the target pc over a local network as well as being connected to a corporate domain.

1. Admin rights are needed on the target
2. An extra ethernet card is needed in the host
3. All networks connections on the target are open with printer and file sharing options enabled
4. The ip and name of the target are listed in system32/etc/host in the host PC
5. A switch is needed and DHCP setting are enable with automatic IP

A good place to start:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg507680.aspx

EDIT:
Basically, this was a nightmare and started dropping its connection. I reverted back to using WinDBG using:

custom scripts to copy everything over to USB
devcon to automactially load the driver 
WinDBG to autoload appropriate settings on startup and load source files in to debug